# What would be the effect of a coastal continental mediterrannean climate on flora?

Tags: climate, flora

I am thinking about creating a continental climate in southern Australia after the creation of a mountain range which created massive agricultural lands, the continental aspect of climate is caused by colossal 'volcanoes' constantly spurring smoke, fog and aerosols which block sunrays and cool up the southern country's climate to large degrees (for exemple, min temperatures -5°C degrees and summer temperatures around 25°C in Adelaide but almost never more) on the coasts and inland but does not affect oceanic currents nor anything which would otherwise influence the climate besides the new mountains.

Ultimately: what would happen to the flora if such 'volcanoes', and then the climate they generate, happen to exist in Australia, specifically the southern part?

Comment: A large mountain range anywhere in Australia would most definitely change the rain patterns to a very noticeable degree. Whatever you mean by "level of dryness" it would certainly not be the same. Ah, and those aerosols will eventually come down, won't they, drastically altering the makeup of the land.

Comment: @AlexP Aerosols changing the landscape? Exactly what I need. I will change the part about the climate not changing though.

Comment: Volcanoes emitting enough junk to constantly affect the local climate will also affect the global climate. Perhaps instead of constantly emitting junk, simply have the existence of the mountain range change the weather pattern so that cool air is pulled up from down south much like how the Rocky Mountains help to pull cool air down from the Arctic into the middle of the US.

Comment: Hi Bangerblade. We call this a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609). They take the form, "here's my big change, how is everything affected?" and they're off-topic. They're too broad and can often not have one best answer. That makes them opinion-based and subject to answers having equal value. All bad things. I'll be honest with you, the odds are you'd have a handful of species die of, a few animals, a few plants, but over all, nothing much would change (which is the answer @TheDemonLord gave before it was deleted). It's hard to kill a biome.

Comment: @JBH, thanks for the advice, for me, it's really hard to understand my own questions. But if the biome does not change much, I'm good with it.

Comment: Perhaps you could get into what is your conceptual problem with the proposed climate - if its mediterranean, why do you think anything other than flora&fauna that usually crop up there would be to expect? Or are you asking for specifics on what makes these organisms thrive in such a climate? In short, that would be because they do not need to have costly adaptions to more hostile climes (long no-water periods, hot, freezing, etc) they outcompete organisms that have this unneccessary baggage

Comment: Late - but you may wish to consult this resource: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Vegetation-zones-of-the-Earth-and-their-corresponding-Koeppen-climate-types_tbl2_260727112. Compares vegetation charts to Koppen climate classifications. Then you can figure things out mostly from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the flora and fauna of Tasmania. As Tasmania is the coolest part of Australia, it would be reasonable to assume that, should other parts of Australia become cooler, the flora and fauna might adapt along similar lines to what has happened in Tasmania.